# Rails and WebSockets using SSL/TLS in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, websocket, localhost, tls1.2

I have a Rails 4.2.x application using ActionCable.

**The goal**

I had to switch from HTTP to HTTPS as I'm using the [Devise FIDO U2F gem](https://github.com/CyberDeck/devise-fido-u2f).
All the application is working fine, my (self-signed) certificate is valid in Chrome (Green lock icon) and present in KeyChain Access with **When using this certificate** from the **Trust** certificat section to **Always Trust**.

I'm migrating WebSocket, which was listening on `ws://my.app.eu:28080`, to `wss://my.app.eu:28080`.

**The problem**

I was using [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) in order to run the ActionCable server, but I found that Puma is using [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine), [which isn't compatible](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1189).
From here, I [migrated ActionCable server to thin](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/actioncable-on-production) but never get it working.

I'm stuck with the error message from the Chrome console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://my.app.eu:28080/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
```

**Weird thing**

I don't know yet why and how but it happened twice to me that it suddenly work in Chome (no more errors and seeing messages arriving through ActionCable to Chrome) but like something was unblocked.

I mean the application is logging when subscribing to queues, when it suddenly worked, I saw those logs in the app's log file.

**Questions**

- What would I miss to have it working?
- Is there a way to see where it is stuck?
- Do you know a place where it is explained how to get Rails development environment working with WebSockets through SSL?

Comment: If you can use nginx to route SSL/TLS requests to a cleantext app, that would probably work for the better. Production environments usually use this design and framework support (as well as application server support) for SSL/TLS is often subpar to the security offered by nginx. You can also try the iodine HTTP/Websocket server. In addition to supporting hijacking for ActionCable, you can use a native websocket and pub/sub support that is usually much faster (I'm the author, I'm biased). iodine assumes SSL/TLS is handled by the proxy (nginx / apache), similar to production environments.

Comment: P.S. from the issue you linked to, I see the issue was fixed with Puma version 3.9.0 and up. Did you try updating your Puma gem to the newest version?

Comment: I wasn't sure the fix was about Puma (honestly I didn't read the entire issue ...). We are using Puma 2.x so let's try to update it :) Thank you @Myst

Comment: Just tried with Puma 3.11.2 but I have the same error than before the upgrade: `Error raised inside the event loop: no implicit conversion of Puma::MiniSSL::Socket into Integer` :(

Comment: @ZedTuX Have you workaround Puma::MiniSSL::Socket into Integer issue?

Comment: @SSR nope, the only way was to switch to Thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to visit https://my.app.eu:28080/ and accept the certificate, then the WSS connections are working.